# Can we deploy QlikSense on serverless architecture?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, qlikview, qliksense, serverless-architecture

Can we deploy **QlikSense/QlikView** on serverless architecture?
Currently using Monolithic architecture, any other way to move on to serverless?

Comment: Can you please explain in a bit more details what are you after?

Comment: I am learning serverless architecture currently. But working with QlikView/QlikSense. So just want to know if we can have QlikView/QlikSense with serverless architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am not familiar with Qlik's products, it is unlikely they would be suitable for serverless architecture.

Companies generally offer the products either as:

- Downloadable products that you run on your own server (which could be a virtual server in the cloud), *or*
- Software-as-a-Service, where you access their website directly and no server is required (eg Salesforce)

"Serverless architecture" is a design decision that can be made when designing a software product. It means the the application is broken-down into small components ('microservices') that can be run on services like AWS Lambda, with no actual server.

However, such architecture would normally only be used for your *own* applications that you create. If another company has designed their system to be 'serverless', then they would normally run it on a cloud system (eg AWS) and offer it to users as Software-as-a-Service. It would be highly unusual to have a 'download' product that runs on a serverless architecture.

I notice that Qlik has product offerings that run on AWS ([AWS Marketplace: Qlik](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/seller-profile?id=ba4c05a7-e7ff-462b-a4d6-99d3f6e77d1f)), which runs on an Amazon EC2 instance, rather than serverless.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the Qlik Core product then yes Qlik can be deployed on an elastic containerised enviroment. But then as I understand it you don't get the standard objects and visualisations, user management etc. So you have to code your own stuff that ties into the Qlik Data Analytics Engine via apis.

From https://core.qlik.com/why-qlik-core/

*So, how do you get it? Licensing info here but let’s talk components
Linux-based Associative Engine  – provided as a Docker image with built-in support for Amazon Web Services, Microsoft Azure and Google Cloud Platform
Supporting APIs  – these ingest your data into the Qlik Associative Engine through connectors
Supporting Open Source Libraries  – these various libraries by Qlik expose the engine to help you build solutions faster
It’s all language agnostic but JavaScript lovers will find it easier to work with given the number of our open source tools available in JavaScript. Other top languages and tools used include R, Go, Shell, C#, Python, Java and D3. Qlik Core can also be managed with the orchestration tool of your choice for implementing, scaling and managing containerized applications.*

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what exactly are you building. As `The Budac` mentioned you can use `Qlik Core`

If you just want invoke `Qlik` API (for example some automation jobs) then serverless functions are making sense.

`Qlik Sense` (both `Enterprise` and `Kubernetes` versions) expose a lot more different API which can be called from technically everywhere.

`QlikView` on the other hand is more ... conservative. QV is an older software and the API/integrations are more limited. For example: to call the `Management API` you have to be on the same domain as QV. Personally I've only connected to QV `Management API` only with `C#` and pretty sure you cant use `JS`/`Node`